# iframe in bootstrap grid system does not work

Tags: html, iframe, bootstrap-grid

When I have some nested grid colums like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        some text
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
               second text
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                third text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
</div>
```

Everything works pretty well.
The text "some text" is first und under this text there is "second text" and "third text".

But when I change "some text" with a google maps iframe like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <iframe class="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/..." width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
               second text
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                third text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
</div>
```

the order of the columns is broken e.g. "second text" is above the iframe then.

[screenshot with iframe in nested columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8n5s.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just tested it and everything seems to work just fine, could you please give us more info or a screenshot?

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this could help:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <iframe class="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d317718.69319292053!2d-0.3817765050863085!3d51.528307984912544!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75%3A0x52963a5addd52a99!2sLondon!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1533121813728" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3"> second text </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9"> third text </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not change anything.

Comment: Have you got any custom css which is running on your page? As you can see from the snippet everything is working quite right